# Flutter - Remove escape sequence in dart

Tags: dart, flutter, unescapestring

To decode API response string to JSON, `json.decode()` works fine.
This will parse a JSON string similar to

```
{ "Response" : {"Responsecode" : "1" , "Response" : "Success"}}
```

But in my case, the response comes in the serialized form like:

```
{\"Response\" : {\"Responsecode\" : \"0\" , \"Response\" : \"Success\"}}
```

`json.decode()` won’t work.

In Java, I used `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson()` for the same problem.
I searched for Dart but couldn’t find how to unescape characters in a string.

**Edit:**
Suppose, the value of key data is `abc"de`
So, its corresponding JSON would be `{"data":"abc\"de"}`
And hence during serialization, this json string is escaped to give `{\"data\":\"abc\\\"de\"}` as the response, which is sent by the API.
So, my intention is to remove the escape sequences, so that I can get the string `{"data":"abc\"de"}`, which would later be decoded using `json.decode()`. Removing the escape sequences was done using `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson()` in java.

Comment: What encoding are you using for the quotation marks? If I try to replicate your error, I have problems even with the first string. But if I use normal quotation marks " then both string work correctly.

Comment: Please check the example I added in the edit part of the question. Also, no special quotation marks are used, just the normal double quotes.

Comment: Maybe you should try to serialize and then scape, or the contrary to what you do. I mean that the normal quotes should not be scaped. I tell you this because if I feed `{"data":"abc\\\"de"}` to `json.decode()` it works ok. So only the quote in the middle should be scaped.

Comment: I can't make changes in the API, as it is live for the android project. However, doing json.decode twice does work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`json.decode` can decode single strings too, so you should be able to just call it twice. The first time it'll return you a string (where the escape characters have been decoded) and the second time it'll decode that string into the map:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var a = r'''"{\"Response\" : {\"Responsecode\" : \"0\" , \"Response\" : \"Success\"}}"''';
  var b = json.decode(json.decode(a));
  print(b['Response']['Responsecode']); // 0
  print(b['Response']['Response']); // Success
}
```

Comment: How can I put a string in triple quotes ''' ''', if I received the string from an API?

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes it's hard to answer without understanding what you're trying to do. You can't/shouldn't need to use triple quotes. The triple quotes just affect how the literal string is parsed in the Dart source file. If your string is a variable populated at runtime, it's not appearing literally in the source code so there's nowhere to have triple quotes.