# How to parse json data if it has escape characters in response with dart or flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

my json response is `{"quoteText":"You\'re not obligated to win. You\'re obligated to keep trying to do the best you can every day.", "quoteAuthor":"Marian Edelman"}` and I am trying to decode by `Map<String, dynamic> quoteData = jsonDecode(response.body);` but getting this exception

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
    E/flutter ( 5814): FormatException: Unrecognized string escape (at character 20)
    E/flutter ( 5814): {"quoteText":"You\'re not obligated to win. You\'re obligated to keep tryin...
    E/flutter ( 5814):                    ^
    E/flutter ( 5814): 
    E/flutter ( 5814): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:1358:5)
```

Tried by `json.decode()` and by doing [flutter-remove-escape-sequence-in-dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52774561/flutter-remove-escape-sequence-in-dart) but no luck. Any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't [valid json](https://www.json.org/). Single quotes should not be escaped. Either you should get the source to fix it, or you can try to fix the string yourself by wholesale replacing any occurrence of `\'` with `'`.

```
String fixed = badString.replaceAll(r"\'", "'");
json.decode(fixed);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I am using a third party API service to which I cannot make any changes. This thing worked for me `jsonDecode(response.body.replaceAll(r"\'", "'"));`